# How to push the hyperlink value to another worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, office365

I have a work book in MS Excel with two work sheets. The first one is called "List Data" and it's where I store the data for the drop down menus on the second page, called "Primary Form". One of my lists are hyperlinks that I want my users to be able to click on, however the hyperlink functionality (web address, etc.) doesn't get pushed to the Primary Form. Is there a way to accomplish this?

MS Excel 365

Comment: What do you mean the hyperlinks aren't pushed to "Primary Form"?

Comment: Primary Form is the name of my second work sheet, I just added it for reference and easier identification of the two sheets. I have the hyperlink set on the List Data page and the cell is 'named' so that I can access it on the Primary Form page, in my drop down menu